# How to write JQuery template in js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, razor, jquery-templates

I have some JQuery template codes that is written in the `.cshtml` file, but would like to move it to the `js` file.  But the js file is not recognizing the `<script></script>`.

Here is the example of the `tmpl`.

```
<<
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="searchResult">
    <li><a href="#" data-name="${Name}">${Name}</a></li>
</script>
>>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing to declare this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would advice against mixing template code and script code but thats your design decision.

Try removing the `<script>` tag as the engine may think of it as cake on cake. Script tag in script.

Answer (score 0):

lol, you shouldn't have to include the `<script>` tags in your js file.  Js fiels are "assumed" `<script>`, however i'm unfamiliar with your setup here as what you have between your script tags appears to be very basic html and should go on a html file.  Js is often used for acctual javascript, aka:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).find("a").css("text-decoration", "none");
}); //  this is an example of somthing typically found in a js file whereas

// the following would generally be placed as in a .php VIEW file, thus MVC, Modal View Control
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-name="${Name}">${Name}</a></li>
</ul>
```

also keep in mind my example uses jquery markup so it may not work in plain javascript program